# Semantics: Is a table or a list better for a "list" of details

Tags: html, semantics

I'm thinking, for a list like that:

- **OS** iOS
- **Version** 5.1
- **Size** 12.5MB

(There shouldn't actually be a dot or any other list style in front of it, it just to make it more readable.)

Is it better to use a list (like this for example):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>OS</h3>
        <p>iOS</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or a table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>OS</th>
            <td>iOS</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or is even a **definition list** (`dl`) the most accurate?

Personally I would go with a list, but I'm not sure how to wrap the content semantically correct within the `<li>`-tags.

I've read an interesting article about it ["DEFINITION LISTS VERSUS TABLES"](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/definition-lists-v-tables), but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of HTML5, a `dl` would definitely be the most semantically appropriate:
http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/.

Unless you're planning on listing multiple instances of data/rows in a way that would be tabular, a table wouldn't make sense at all.

I generally prefer lists over tables for reasons like responsive design, but as a rule of thumb unless you're dealing with something that is conceptually a view of a matrix rather than a detail of a single record or otherwise a single set of key/value attributes it would be difficult to justify a table (and no matter what in this case the `dl` is an exact match for the use).

Comment: +1 Thanks for clearing that up. I was already onto it, using a `<dl>`, hoping for an answer like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use table.  You are trying to organize key-value pairs, which I think are easier to convey in a tabular format than a list.  I would use list if you did not include the key names, i.e. if you omitted OS, Version, and Size.